# Laravel production environment

Tags: laravel, deployment, production-environment, production

I've worked on my web app and now it's ready to go on production. For developmnent I used XAMPP on my local machine. I need to deploy the app on a Windows Server 2016 in which other people have access to.
So let's start with some question for you!

**1:**
I suppose that using XAMPP is not a good idea since it doesn't offer a good level of security.
I want to protect my database, my database storage folders and I want to avoid other people to access any part of my environment.

So I actually want to ask you any suggestion on how to deploy my web app avoiding security issues.
I also would like to ask you the better free local environment I can use for production (something like XAMPP but with improved security).

Keep in mind that my web app should only be visible to the local network.

**2:**
Is there a way I can set an hostname for my server in order to make everyone who is connected to the lan able to reach my server with that hostname? Writing the IP with the port isn't good for user experience. I know I can use the "name" of the computer itself, but setting a custom hostname would be better.

**3:**
How should I serve the application? Running the normal command "php artisan serve"? Anyway that way just closing the terminal would result in killing the process so the server will become unavailable.

ANY suggestion would be really appreciated. Is my first approach to deployment so I'm really sorry if my questions are stupid.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Keep in mind that my web app should only be visible to the local network.

For example, your webserver whatever artisan / apache or nginx should only bind to your local IP address, and your incoming firewall should reject external ip's.

Comment: @DannyEbbers thank you for your answer. Other people having access to the server are people that I DON'T absolutely trust, but are qualified people with server managing experience. I know that hostname is related to DNS and I know the process of hostname resolution, but I never had the necessity to apply it in a web app so I'm totally new to this. I appreciate any help, any good documentation, any critic and so on. So feel free to share with me everything you want!